# Mysql convert quote when exporting into .sql

Tags: php, mysql

Everytime if export a table in my MySQL database via phpmyadmin, it convert quotes, double quote, and some dash into weird character. Why ?, 
Here is my MySQL Code :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oasis_top_slide_show` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `image` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `oasis_top_slide_show`
--

INSERT INTO `oasis_top_slide_show` (`id`, `image`, `title`,    `description`, `order_id`) VALUES
(10, 'sYadS7V8Wm.jpeg', 'The Percik Restaurant & Bar', 'Enjoying tropical cocktails at our bar or at the swimming pool during â€œHappy Hourâ€', 7);
```

See --> Enjoying tropical cocktails at our bar or at the swimming pool during â€œHappy Hourâ€

It must be like this --> Enjoying tropical cocktails at our bar or at the swimming pool during "Happy Hour" (DOUBLE QUOTE)

Comment: You need to set connection and table to UTF-8 then, not just `latin1`

Comment: You didn't insert ordinary double quotes yourself. You probably pasted it from your word processor and inserted [typographic quotation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark), which aren't in the first 127 characters of the unicode set. As @mario said, use UTF-8 on your connection.

Comment: How to set connection and table to UTF-8 ?, in the code above, i already try to put --> CHARSET=utf8 , but it still fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application you're using to display the export file most likely uses some latin1 encoding and the characters â€œ then are encoded by the three bytes E2 80 9C.
In utf-8 those three bytes encode the single `Unicode Character 'LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+201C)`. see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm

I.e. mysql (or the application you were using) exported the data utf-8 encoded but you've viewed them latin1-encoded.

Comment: Maybe, but when i import those code into a new database. The weird character is inserted, not a quote. This will result a weird character printed in the web browser. T.T

Comment: Your import application reads/interprets the data latin1 encoded - but it's utf-8 encoded. Same thing.